# Aeson: parsing dynamic keys as type field

Tags: haskell, aeson

Let's say there is a JSON like:

```
{
  "bob_id" : {
    "name": "bob",
    "age" : 20
  },
  "jack_id" : {
    "name": "jack",
    "age" : 25
  }
}
```

Is it possible to parse it to `[Person]` with `Person` defined like below?

```
data Person = Person {
   id   :: Text
  ,name :: Text
  ,age  :: Int
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? Just parse it an kinda `fold` over the result to convert it to `[Person]`? But I have never used `aeson`. Maybe state what the problem is more clearly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot define an instance for `[Person]` literally, because aeson already includes an instance for `[a]`, however you can create a newtype, and provide an instance for that.

Aeson also includes the instance `FromJSON a => FromJSON (Map Text a)`, which means if aeson knows how to parse something, it knows how to parse a dict of that something.

You can define a temporary datatype resembling a value in the dict, then use the Map instance to define `FromJSON PersonList`, where `newtype PersonList = PersonList [Person]`:

```
data PersonInfo = PersonInfo { infoName :: Text, infoAge :: Int }

instance FromJSON PersonInfo where
    parseJSON (Object v) = PersonInfo <$> v .: "name" <*> v .: "age"
    parseJSON _ = mzero

data Person = Person { id :: Text, name :: Text, age :: Int }
newtype PersonList = PersonList [Person]

instance FromJSON PersonList where
    parseJSON v = fmap (PersonList . map (\(id, PersonInfo name age) -> Person id name age) . M.toList) $ parseJSON v
```

Answer (score 3):

If you enable `FlexibleInstances`, you can make instance for `[Person]`. You can parse your object to `Map Text Value` and then parse each element in map:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax, OverloadedStrings, FlexibleInstances #-}

module Person (
    ) where

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Data.Text.Lazy
import Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M

data Person = Person {
    id ∷ Text,
    name ∷ Text,
    age ∷ Int }
        deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

instance FromJSON [Person] where
    parseJSON v = do
        objs ← parseJSON v ∷ Parser (Map Text Value)
        sequence [withObject "person"
            (\v' → Person i <$> v' .: "name" <*> v' .: "age") obj | 
            (i, obj) ← M.toList objs]

test ∷ Text
test = "{\"bob_id\":{\"name\":\"bob\",\"age\":20},\"jack_id\":{\"name\":\"jack\",\"age\":25}}"

res ∷ Maybe [Person]
res = decode (encodeUtf8 test)
```

Comment: Doesn't that produce inconsistent insances if, say, we were to instantiate `FromJSON Person`

Answer (score 2):

[mniip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32422072/1477667) converts the JSON `Object` to a `Map`, which leads to a result list sorted by ID. If you don't need the results sorted in that fashion, it's probably better to use a more direct approach to speed things up. In particular, an `Object` is really just a `HashMap Text Value`, so we can use `HashMap` operations to work with it.

Note that I renamed the `id` field to `ident`, because most Haskell programmers will assume that `id` refers to the identity function in `Prelude` or to the more general identity arrow in `Control.Category`.

```
module Aes where
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HMS

data PersonInfo = PersonInfo { infoName :: Text, infoAge :: Int }

instance FromJSON PersonInfo where
-- Use mniip's definition here

data Person = Person { ident :: Text, name :: Text, age :: Int }

newtype PersonList = PersonList [Person]

instance FromJSON PersonList where
  parseJSON (Object v) = PersonList <$> HMS.foldrWithKey go (pure []) v
    where
      go i x r = (\(PersonInfo nm ag) rest -> Person i nm ag : rest) <$>
                     parseJSON x <*> r
  parseJSON _ = empty
```

Note that, like [Alexander VoidEx Ruchkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32422275/1477667), this sequences the conversion from `PersonInfo` to `Person` explicitly within the `Parser` monad. It would therefore be easy to modify it to produce a parse error if the `Person` fails some sort of high-level validation. Alexander's answer also demonstrates the utility of the `withObject` combinator, which I'd have used if I'd known it existed.